Index out of range when using Array.FindIndex
I'm currently attempting to solve a Leetcode problem:

Given a non-empty array of integers nums, every element appears twice
except for one. Find that single one.
You must implement a solution with a linear runtime complexity and use
only constant extra space.

My "solution":
public class Solution
{
    public int SingleNumber(int[] nums)
    {
        int[] nums2 = new int[nums.Length];

        if (nums.Length == 1)
        {
            return nums[0];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!nums2.Contains(nums[i]))
            {
                nums2[i] = nums[i];
            }
            else
            {
                var x = Array.IndexOf(nums2, nums[i]);
                nums[x] = 0;
                nums[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        var index = Array.FindIndex(nums, value => value != 0);
        return nums[index];
    }
}

It passed 5 tests but then gives me this error:

Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was
outside the bounds of the array.
At Solution.SingleNumber(Int32[] nums)
At __DriverSolution__.__Helper__(Int32[] param_1)
At __Driver__.Main(String[] args)


I'm suspecting it might be because of the Array.FindIndex, I read that it will return -1 if no value can be found. I wonder however, how could that even happen because there is always a value that's appearing twice in the original array, or is there some other logical flaw in my code?

JFYI your solution does not have "linear runtime complexity" it has quadratic (O(n^2)) one.

var result = nums.Aggregate((s, a) => s ^ a);

Xor is a standard solution of this problem: the intuition is that if we xor items of the array then duplicates will cancel out one another since a ^ a == 0 and
we'll have the single one.
Linq oneliner:
using System.Linq;

...

public class Solution {
    public int SingleNumber(int[] nums) => nums.Aggregate((s, a) => s ^ a);
}

No Linq solution
using System.Linq;

...

public class Solution {
    public int SingleNumber(int[] nums) {
        int result = 0;

        foreach (int num in nums) 
            result ^= num;

        return result;
    }
}

In c# array doesn't have Contains method (so you use some custom implementation); the algorithm itself seems to be correct (even if it's not optimal) that's why I think the problem is in the Contains. We can change if (!nums2.Contains(nums[i])) into (Array.IndexOf(nums2, nums[i]) < 0). https://dotnetfiddle.net/vPRjr8

I've tried this (Array.IndexOf(nums2, nums[i]) < 0) but it doesnt resolve the error :/

@ByGoalZ: Could you provide test array, please? I can reproduce the issue if expected condition is not met, e.g. if I pass nums = {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3} - all values are duplicated, and there's no single one; or if we have a triple value: {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1} - note that 1 appears three times.

With your code, you have assumed that no element of the input array will ever be 0, which is incorrect as the problem states they could be any integer in the range [-3e4, 3e4]. You must use a value outside of this range to mark an element as not being the answer, e.g. int.MinValue or int.MaxValue.
A working solution based on your code:
public int SingleNumber(int[] nums)
{
    int[] nums2 = new int[nums.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < nums2.Length; i++) nums2[i] = int.MinValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++) 
    {
        if (!nums2.Contains(nums[i]))
            nums2[i] = nums[i];
        else
            nums[Array.IndexOf(nums2, nums[i])] = nums[i] = int.MinValue;
    }
    return nums[Array.FindIndex(nums, value => value != int.MinValue)];
}

